# Onsen UI not working in AngularJS project

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, onsen-ui

Im trying to use Onsen with AngularJS but when i call the scripts i have error of 404 not found, this are the scripts that arent working

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="onsenui.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="onsen-css-components.css"/>
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="onsenui.min.js"></script>
<script src="angular-onsenui.min.js"></script>
```

i have installed onsen ui with npm, and i do have it in the node modules, and i have called it in the module too

```
var app = angular.module('app',['ngRoute','app.routes', 'app.core', 
'onsen']);
app.controller('AppCtrl',function(){});
```

any idea what can i do to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

No need to call this via script tag if you already have installed via NPM.

Take advantage of the module distribution, so you can simply call it with [`requirejs`](http://requirejs.org/docs/node.html).

But there is literally gazillion projects on the web. For example [this](https://github.com/ipluser/angularjs-requirejs-boilerplate) boilerplate can help you.

Comment: all i have to do then is var require = require(node_modules/onsenui) ?

Comment: Yes, but you should include the `.js` file from module ... so `require(../node_modules/onsenui/js/angular-onsenui.js)`, or something similar. Take a look inside the node_modules. You can see the structure, and the file is definitely in the JS folder. Don't forget to include the CSS as well in your loader.

Comment: i installed with npm, now when i try to use it, gives me error of "require is not defined"

Comment: `npm install requirejs`

Comment: yea, i did it, now when i try to use var require = require('requirejs'), gives me error of require not defined

Comment: You need to include that as a `script`. [Here](https://www.startersquad.com/blog/angularjs-requirejs/) is a tutorial. It's 2 min. read.